# getting Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException & Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

Hello I am new to Android and I am currently developing a simple login and registration android app using MySql, PHP and JSON. I have created a Database and tables in xampp(local server). Whenever I tried to register I am getting a ton of errors. There are already similar questions like this but the answers didn't help me out. Thanks in Advance.

Here is my code

1. JSONParser

   ```
   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStream;
   import java.io.InputStreamReader;
   import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
   import java.util.List;

   import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
   import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
   import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
   import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
   import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
   import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
   import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
   import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
   import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
   import org.json.JSONException;
   import org.json.JSONObject;

   import android.util.Log;

   public class JSONParser {

   static InputStream is = null;
   static JSONObject jObj = null;
   static String json = "";

   // constructor
   public JSONParser() {

   }

   public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

       // Making HTTP request
       try {
           // defaultHttpClient
           DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
           HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

           HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
           HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
           is = httpEntity.getContent();

       } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       try {
           BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                   is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
           String line = null;
           while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
               sb.append(line + "\n");
           }
           is.close();
           json = sb.toString();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
       }

       // try parse the string to a JSON object
       try {
           jObj = new JSONObject(json);
       } catch (JSONException e) {
           Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
       }

       // return JSON String
       return jObj;

       }
       // function get json from url
       // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
       public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
           List<NameValuePair> params) {

       // Making HTTP request
       try {

           // check for request method
           if(method == "POST"){
               // request method is POST
               // defaultHttpClient
               DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
               HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
               httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

               HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
               HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
               is = httpEntity.getContent();

           }else if(method == "GET"){
               // request method is GET
               DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
               String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
               url += "?" + paramString;
               HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

               HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
               HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
               is = httpEntity.getContent();
           }           

       } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       try {
           BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                   is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
           String line = null;
           while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
               sb.append(line + "\n");
           }
           is.close();
           json = sb.toString();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
       }

       // try parse the string to a JSON object
       try {
           jObj = new JSONObject(json);
       } catch (JSONException e) {
           Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
       }

       // return JSON String
       return jObj;

      }
      }
   ```
2. Register.java

   ```
      import android.app.Activity;
      import android.os.Bundle;

      import java.util.ArrayList;
      import java.util.List;

      import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
      import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
      import org.json.JSONException;
      import org.json.JSONObject;

      import android.app.ProgressDialog;
      import android.content.Intent;
      import android.os.AsyncTask;
      import android.util.Log;
      import android.view.View;
      import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
      import android.widget.Button;
      import android.widget.EditText;
      import android.widget.Toast;

      // Creating the Java class 

      public class Register extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
      // Creating variables for username and password...
      private EditText user,pass;
      private Button register;
      // Creating the progressDialog...
      private ProgressDialog pDialog;
      // Creating reference for the JSONParser...
      JSONParser jsonparser = new JSONParser();
     // Getting the url to run the php register script..
     // Here I am using a localserver since I dont have access to a real server..
     private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://http://127.0.0.1/webservice/register.php";

     // Creating ids for messages...
     private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
     private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

     // Creating the onCreate method...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);
    // getting references for the username,password and the button elements

   user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.get_username);
   pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.get_password);
   register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
   // Creating onClickListener for the button...
   register.setOnClickListener(this);

   }

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
   // getting method for create new user...
   new CreateUser().execute();

   Intent intent = new Intent(this, Usersuccess.class);

   }
   // Creating a new class called CreateUser...
   class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

   /**
    * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
    * */
   boolean failure = false;
   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
       super.onPreExecute();
       pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
       pDialog.setMessage("Creating User...");
       pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
       pDialog.setCancelable(true);
       pDialog.show();
   }
   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
       // Check for success tag
       int success;
       String username = user.getText().toString();
       String password = pass.getText().toString();
       try {
           // Building Parameters
           List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
           params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
           params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

           Log.d("request!", "starting");

           //Posting user data to script
           JSONObject json = jsonparser.makeHttpRequest(
                  LOGIN_URL, "POST", params1);

           // full json response
           Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

           // json success element
           success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
           if (success == 1) {
               Log.d("User Created!", json.toString());
               finish();
               return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
           }else{
               Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
               return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

           }
       } catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       return null;
   }
   /**
    * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
    * **/
   protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
       // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
       pDialog.dismiss();
       if (file_url != null){
           Toast.makeText(Register.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }

   }

   }



   }
   ```
3. Login.java

   ```
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
   import android.widget.Button;

   //Creating the class that extends the Activity class

   public class LoginScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.login_screen);

   Button Signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup);
   Signup.setOnClickListener(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
   // Creating intent for Signup process..
   Intent i = new Intent(LoginScreen.this,Register.class);
   startActivity(i);

   }

   }
   ```

This is my logcat:

```html
10-31 12:45:28.441: D/request!(359): starting
10-31 12:45:30.041: W/System.err(359): java.net.UnknownHostException: http
10-31 12:45:30.041: W/System.err(359):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:506)
10-31 12:45:30.051: W/System.err(359):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:294)
10-31 12:45:30.051: W/System.err(359):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:256)
10-31 12:45:30.051: W/System.err(359):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
10-31 12:45:30.051: W/System.err(359):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
10-31 12:45:30.061: W/System.err(359):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
10-31 12:45:30.061: W/System.err(359):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
10-31 12:45:30.071: W/System.err(359):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
10-31 12:45:30.071: W/System.err(359):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
10-31 12:45:30.080: W/System.err(359):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
10-31 12:45:30.080: W/System.err(359):  at com.augustasoftsol.gmoapp.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:96)
10-31 12:45:30.080: W/System.err(359):  at com.augustasoftsol.gmoapp.Register$CreateUser.doInBackground(Register.java:99)
10-31 12:45:30.080: W/System.err(359):  at com.augustasoftsol.gmoapp.Register$CreateUser.doInBackground(Register.java:1)
10-31 12:45:30.091: W/System.err(359):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
10-31 12:45:30.101: W/System.err(359):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
10-31 12:45:30.101: W/System.err(359):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
10-31 12:45:30.101: W/System.err(359):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
10-31 12:45:30.132: W/System.err(359):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
10-31 12:45:30.132: W/System.err(359):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
10-31 12:45:30.132: E/Buffer Error(359): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
10-31 12:45:30.141: E/JSON Parser(359): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
10-31 12:45:30.151: W/dalvikvm(359): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
10-31 12:45:30.171: E/AndroidRuntime(359): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
10-31 12:45:30.171: E/AndroidRuntime(359): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-31 12:45:30.171: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
10-31 12:45:30.171: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
10-31 12:45:30.171: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
10-31 12:45:30.171: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
10-31 12:45:30.171: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
10-31 12:45:30.171: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
10-31 12:45:30.171: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
10-31 12:45:30.171: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
10-31 12:45:30.171: E/AndroidRuntime(359): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-31 12:45:30.171: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at com.augustasoftsol.gmoapp.Register$CreateUser.doInBackground(Register.java:103)
10-31 12:45:30.171: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at com.augustasoftsol.gmoapp.Register$CreateUser.doInBackground(Register.java:1)
10-31 12:45:30.171: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
10-31 12:45:30.171: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
10-31 12:45:30.171: E/AndroidRuntime(359):  ... 4 more
10-31 12:45:32.121: E/WindowManager(359): Activity com.augustasoftsol.gmoapp.Register has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405a3fe0 that was originally added here
10-31 12:45:32.121: E/WindowManager(359): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.augustasoftsol.gmoapp.Register has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405a3fe0 that was originally added here
10-31 12:45:32.121: E/WindowManager(359):  at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:258)
10-31 12:45:32.121: E/WindowManager(359):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
10-31 12:45:32.121: E/WindowManager(359):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
10-31 12:45:32.121: E/WindowManager(359):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
10-31 12:45:32.121: E/WindowManager(359):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
10-31 12:45:32.121: E/WindowManager(359):  at com.augustasoftsol.gmoapp.Register$CreateUser.onPreExecute(Register.java:82)
10-31 12:45:32.121: E/WindowManager(359):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
10-31 12:45:32.121: E/WindowManager(359):  at com.augustasoftsol.gmoapp.Register.onClick(Register.java:63)
10-31 12:45:32.121: E/WindowManager(359):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
10-31 12:45:32.121: E/WindowManager(359):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
10-31 12:45:32.121: E/WindowManager(359):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-31 12:45:32.121: E/WindowManager(359):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-31 12:45:32.121: E/WindowManager(359):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-31 12:45:32.121: E/WindowManager(359):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-31 12:45:32.121: E/WindowManager(359):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-31 12:45:32.121: E/WindowManager(359):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-31 12:45:32.121: E/WindowManager(359):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-31 12:45:32.121: E/WindowManager(359):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-31 12:45:32.121: E/WindowManager(359):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-31 12:45:35.381: I/Process(359): Sending signal. PID: 359 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Your constant `LOGIN_URL = "http://http://127.0.0.1/webservice/register.php";` seems incorrect

Comment: Yeah I did that. I changed but still it did not work out.

Answer (score 0):

When using local server and testing on an emulator

Use,

```
private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/webservice/register.php";
```

And if you are testing the application on a real device, use the IP of the computer that is hosting the local server.

I hope it helps!

Comment: I have already used as private static final String. but it is showing the same error

Comment: `10.0.2.2` please note this IP i have used. This has to be used when you are testing the application on an emulator